# How to set my computerId into primary key?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Here's my code in domain. I wanted to set my computerId into a primary key. But still display on my table(index). Thanks

```
package com.data

class ComputerInformation {

    String computerId;
    String computerName;
    String status;
    String location;
    String serial;
    String monitorSerial;
    String keyboardSerial;
    String mouseSerial;
    String cpuSerial;
    String avrSerial;
    String harddiskSerial;

    static constraints = {
        computerId(unique:true)
        computerName(blank:false)
        status(blank:false)
        location(blank:false)
        serial(blank:false)
        monitorSerial(blank:false)
        keyboardSerial(blank:false)
        mouseSerial(blank:false)
        cpuSerial(blank:false)
        avrSerial(blank:false)
        harddiskSerial(blank:false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this,

```
static mapping = {
        id name: 'computerId'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
But i would like to do is the user should not be able to input the computer ID but the computer id still display on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of changing PK, return id as a computerId variable?

```
package com.data

class ComputerInformation {

    String computerName;
    String status;
    String location;
    String serial;
    String monitorSerial;
    String keyboardSerial;
    String mouseSerial;
    String cpuSerial;
    String avrSerial;
    String harddiskSerial;

    static constraints = {
        computerName(blank:false)
        status(blank:false)
        location(blank:false)
        serial(blank:false)
        monitorSerial(blank:false)
        keyboardSerial(blank:false)
        mouseSerial(blank:false)
        cpuSerial(blank:false)
        avrSerial(blank:false)
        harddiskSerial(blank:false)
    }

    def getComputerId(){
        return id
    }
}
```

Moreover if you need computerId as a String, you can change getComputerId function to:

```
String getComputerId(){
        return id.toString()
}
```